# Python - Adding elements of the same index in a nested list, then calculating the average

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list as follows:

```
[
  [0, 5, -3, 5, 0, 0],
  [-3, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0],
  [1, 0, 5, 0, -5, 0],
  [-3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 5]
]
```

I need to calculate the sum and the average of the elements that share the same index, then the results will be added to a new list. For example, items of index 0 of those inner lists would be added together:

```
0 + (-3) + 1 + (-3) = -5
```

Then the sum will be divided by the count of numbers (0 is not included) for the average:

```
average = -5/3 = -1.66666667
```

Finally, it will be added to a new list.

I was expecting the result would look like this

```
[
  -1.66667,
  5.0,
  1.5,
  5.0,
  0.0,
  5
]
```

I tried this:

```
for i in range(0, len(rating_values)):
    for j in range(0, len(rating_values[i])):
        total = 0
        count = 0
        if rating_values[i][j] != 0:
            total += rating_values[i][j]
            count += 1
        average_rating = total / count if count > 0 else 0
        average_list.append(average_rating)
```

But I got this:

```
[0, 5.0, -3.0, 5.0, 0, 0, -3.0, 0, 1.0, 0, 5.0, 0, 1.0, 0, 5.0, 0, -5.0, 0, -3.0, 0, 3.0, 0, 0, 5.0]
```

Is there a way that I can loop through the items of the same index (for those inner lists) only in Python?

Comment: you have everything down apart from a slight indentation error in your last 2 lines

Comment: If my solution helped you, can you please accept the answer to close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little modification, you can achieve it. You should iterate through the columns first. Then, go through the rows for each of these columns. As I can see, you also placed the sum and count variables inside the inner loop, which causes them to reset with every row, and appended the average inside the inner loop as well, resulting in multiple entries per index.

```
rating_values = [[0, 5, -3, 5, 0, 0], [-3, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0], [1, 0, 5, 0, -5, 0], [-3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 5]]
average_list = []

# Loop through each index
for j in range(len(rating_values[0])):  # Assumes all sublists are of equal length
    total = 0
    count = 0
    # Loop through each list for the current index
    for i in range(len(rating_values)):
        if rating_values[i][j] != 0:
            total += rating_values[i][j]
            count += 1
    # Compute the average; if count is 0, average is set to 0
    average_rating = total / count if count > 0 else 0
    average_list.append(round(average_rating, 5))  # rounding to 5 decimal places

print(average_list)
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(list)):` should never be used. It should nearly always be `for element in list:` or `for ix, element in enumerate(list):`

Answer (score 2):

You should write a discrete function to calculate the value you need. This function will sum a list of integers, count the number of zeros in the list then divide the sum by the difference between the length of the list and the zero count.

This could result in a ZeroDivisionError exception.

You can use *zip()* to conveniently iterate over your input list

```
data = [[0, 5, -3, 5, 0, 0], [-3, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0], [1, 0, 5, 0, -5, 0], [-3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 5]]

def average(e):
    try:
        return sum(e) / (len(e) - e.count(0))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        pass

result = [average(e) for e in zip(*data)]

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[-1.6666666666666667, 5.0, 1.5, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of task (multi-dimensional array), you will see a huge benefit in using `numpy`. Not only is it more efficient (when large amount of data), but also everything is more natural.

With `numpy` you can get what you want in 1 line of code (`y = ...`):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([
  [0, 5, -3, 5, 0, 0],
  [-3, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0],
  [1, 0, 5, 0, -5, 0],
  [-3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 5]
])
y = np.sum(x, axis=0) / np.sum(x != 0, axis=0)
print(y)  # [-1.66666667  5.          1.5         5.          0.          5.        ]
```

Here you do a sum "vertically" (`axis=0`), and you divide this *vector* by the vertical sum of 0 and 1 values (1 if `!= 0` and 0 if `== 0`), i.e. you are dividing by the count of non-zero elements in each column.

Comment: Vulnerable to divide by zero, but otherwise the nice way to do it

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks! Not really vulnerable, no error in the case of only zeroes in a column, but only a `nan`, which is logical: `[-1.66666667  nan  1.5   5.  0.   5.]`

Comment: https://trinket.io/python3/d8883d5153

Comment: @MatBailie Yes it's just a RuntimeWarning, it doesn't stop the execution of the next lines of code.